# This expression has type int but is here used with type unit

Tags: syntax, f#

I'm trying to get the exact equivalent (not functional) of this vb.net code in F#:

```
Function FastPow(ByVal num As Double, ByVal exp As Integer) As Double
   Dim res As Double = 1
   If exp < 1 Then
      If exp = 0 Then Return res
      exp = -exp
      num = 1 / num
   End If
   Do While exp > 1
      If exp Mod 2 = 1 Then 
         res = res * num
      num = num * num
      exp = exp >> 1
   Loop
   Return res * num
End Function
```

I wrote this:

```
let FastPow num exp =
   let mutable ex = exp
   let mutable res = 1
   let mutable n = num
   if ex < 1 then
      if ex = 0 then res
      ex <- -ex
      n <- 1 / n
   while ex > 1 do
      if (ex % 2 = 1) then 
         res <- res * n
      n <- n * n
      exp >>> 1
   res * n
```

but in the line "if ex = 0 then res" at res I got an error:
"This expression has type int but is here used with type unit". 
I cannot understand why it gives me that error.
Edit: i actually got a warning as well:
"This expression should have type 'unit', but has type 'int'."
at "if (ex % 2 = 1) then"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In F#, a function's return value is the last expression evaluated in the function. So, lets focus on the following:

```
   if ex < 1 then
      if ex = 0 then res    (* <--- this is not an early return *)
      ex <- -ex             (* <--- F# evaluates this code after the *)
      n <- 1 / n            (*      if statement *)
```

Additionally, if statements have return values, which also happens to be the last value executed in the if statement. If an if statement isn't the return value of a function, it should have the return type `unit`. Notice that variable assignment has a return type of `unit`.

We need to rewrite your code to accomodate your early return, so we can do this:

```
let FastPow2 num exp =
    if exp = 0 then 1
    else
        let mutable ex = exp
        let mutable res = 1
        let mutable n = num
        if ex < 1 then
            ex <- -ex
            n <- 1 / n
        while ex > 1 do
            if (ex % 2 = 1) then  (* still have a bug here *)
                res <- res * n
            n <- n * n
            exp >>> 1  (* <--- this is not a variable assignment *)
        res * n
```

We still have a bug, although I think F# is reporting the error in the wrong place. The expression `exp >>> 1` returns an int, it does not assign any variables, so its not equivalent to your original C# code. I think you meant to use the `ex` variable instead. We can fix your code as follows:

```
let FastPow2 num exp =
    if exp = 0 then 1
    else
        let mutable ex = exp
        let mutable res = 1
        let mutable n = num
        if ex < 1 then
            ex <- -ex
            n <- 1 / n
        while ex > 1 do
            if (ex % 2 = 1) then 
                res <- res * n
            n <- n * n
            ex <- ex >>> 1
        res * n
```

Now your function is fixed, but its really really ugly. Lets convert it to more idiomatic F#. You can replace the if statement with pattern matching, and replace the while loop with recursion:

```
let FastPow2 num exp =
    match exp with 
    | 0 -> 1
    | _ ->
        let rec loop ex res n =
            if ex > 1 then
                let newRes = if ex % 2 = 1 then res * n else res
                loop (ex >>> 1) newRes (n * n)
            else res * n

        let ex, n = if exp < 1 then (-exp, 1 / num) else (exp, num)
        loop ex 1 n
```

Much better! Theres still some more room to beautify this function, but you get the idea :)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is for an if statment to resolve to a value rather than unit, you need both the "then" part and the "else" part, both of which resolve to the same type.

For example:

```
let a = if true then 1;;
```

Will generate the same error - expression has type int but used with type unit.

However:

```
let a = if true then 1 else 0;;
```

Will evaluate to int without an error.

Answer (score 1):

This is about as close as you can get, as others have already said you can't jump out of the middle of a functional and there's one place were you don't update a variable (at the bottom of the while).

```
let FastPow num exp =
   let mutable exp = exp
   let mutable res = 1
   let mutable n = num
   match exp with
   | O -> n <- num
   | _ when exp < 1 ->
      exp <- -exp
      n <- 1 / n
   | _ ->
       while exp > 1 do
          if (exp % 2 = 1) then 
             res <- res * n
          n <- n * n
          exp <- exp >>> 1
   res * n
```

I could be more beautiful if it was written more functionally.

Answer (score 0):

It means that after `then` there should be some expression, but you have integer value. You cannot jump out from the middle of the function.

**Edit**

"If" didn't work because of

```
ex >>> 1

should be

ex <- ex >>> 1
```

Here's code that works:

```
let FastPow num exp =
    let calcExp num exp = 
        let mutable res = 1.0
        let mutable n   = num
        let mutable ex  = exp
        while ex > 1 do
            if ((ex % 2) = 1) then  
                res <- res * n
            n <- n * n
            ex <- ex >>> 1
        res * n

    match exp with
    | ex when ex = 0 -> 1.0
    | ex when ex < 0 -> calcExp (1.0/num) -exp
    | _ -> calcExp num exp
```

I just take out calculation as separate function, and at the end there is checking for arguments

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers. This is the current non-functional version.

```
let FastPow num exp =
   let mutable ex = exp
   let mutable res = 1.0
   let mutable n = num
   if ex = 0 then 1.0
   else 
      if ex < 1 then
         ex <- -ex
         n <- 1.0 / n
      while ex > 1 do
         if (ex % 2 = 1) then res <- res * n
         n <- n * n
         ex <- ex >>> 1
      res * n
```

Now that I have a working version I will try to make it more functional but that's outside the scope of this question.
EDIT: I got better results that I expected so I will post the recursive version optimized for speed (slightly faster than the iterative version and about 10% faster than the C# iterative version (!!!) in my computer):

```
let rec loop res num exp =
   if exp = 0 then res
   elif (exp % 2) = 1 then loop (res * num) (num * num) (exp / 2)
   else loop res (num * num) (exp / 2)

let FP num exp =
   let n = if exp < 0 then 1.0 / num else num
   loop 1.0 n (Math.Abs(exp))
```