# Expression here has type int but is used with type unit

Tags: f#

I have the following code:

```
#light
let rec fib n = 
    if n=0 || n=1 then 1 //<- here on the "1"
    n + fib n-1 + fib n-2
```

How do i fix this?
[i've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/420294/this-expression-has-type-int-but-is-here-used-with-type-unit) but it didn't help]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are missing an `else`. You also need some extra parenthesis:

```
#light
let rec fib n =
  if n=0 || n=1 then 1
  else n + fib (n-1) + fib (n-2)
```

Comment: For informational purposes: Without the parens, it's read as `(n) + (fib n) - (1) + (fib n) - (2)`.

Comment: @Chuck: Yes, and calling `fib n` from `fib n` results in an infinite recursion ending in a Stack Overflow... ;^)